# CSS Animation slider

Tags: html, css, animation, sass, slider

I am trying to do an animation slider using only CSS. I have 3 pictures that I want to slide horizontally. My question is that I can add them transformation, but no animation The animation has to stop for a few seconds on each image. Anyone has ideas how to manage it? I use sass.

**Code:**

```css
.slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  // width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  .slides {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation: slide 3s steps(2) infinite;
    .slide {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 100px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      img {
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 250px;
      }
      h1 {
        color: #323232;
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 42px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
      }
      h4 {
        font-weight: 200;
        line-height: 32px;
        letter-spacing: 0.9px;
        display: flex;
      }
    }
    //end .slide
    &:after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  //end .slides
  @keyframes slide {
    to {
      transform: translateX(-300vw);
    }
  }
}
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div class="slides">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/testimonial-img-1.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>TANYA - Architect</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, maecenas eget vestibulum justo imperdiet, wisi risus purus augue vulputate voluptate neque, curabitur dolor libero sodales vitae elit massa.</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/testimonial-img-2.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>LINDA - City planner</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, maecenas eget vestibulum justo imperdiet, wisi risus purus augue vulputate voluptate neque, curabitur dolor libero sodales vitae elit massa.</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <img src="images/testimonial-img-3.jpg" alt="" />
      <h1>SANDAR - Developer</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, maecenas eget vestibulum justo imperdiet, wisi risus purus augue vulputate voluptate neque, curabitur dolor libero sodales vitae elit massa.</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: A couple of things with your code, First of all, you're code has the wrong amount of brackets `19`. Secondly your code has a lot of nesting that isn't required. There is no need to nest `.slide` inside `.slider` and `.slides`.  You could accomplish the same thing by writing it at the top level. It's always a good idea to keep nesting levels to a minimum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```css
#outerbox{
 width:700px;
 overflow:hidden;
 
 }
#sliderbox{
 position:relative;
 width:2800px;
 animation:animation 20s infinite;
 
 }
#sliderbox img{
 float:left;
 } 
@keyframes animation{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  }
 100%{
  left:-2800px; 
   }
 
  }
```

```html
<div id="outerbox">
<div id="sliderbox">
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/1.jpg"/> 
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/2.jpg"/>
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/3.jpg"/>
```

**Ok try this**

```css
#outerbox{
 width:700px;
 }
#sliderbox{
 position:relative;
 width:2800px;
 animation:animation 20s infinite;
 }
#sliderbox img{
 float:left;
 } 
@keyframes animation{
 0%{
  left:0px;
  }
 20%{
  left:0px; 
   }
 25%{
  left:-700px; 
   }
 45%{
  left:-700px; 
   }
 50%{
  left:-1400px; 
   }
 70%{
  left:-1400px; 
   }
 
  }
```

```html
<div id="outerbox">
<div id="sliderbox">
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/1.jpg"/> 
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/2.jpg"/>
<img src="http://labs.qnimate.com/slider/3.jpg"/>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I want that on every image, animation stops for a few seconds. My mistake I havent added it before.

Answer (score 0):

Your css, fixed:

```
.slider{
      position: relative;
      height: 100vh;
      // width: 100vw;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: block;
    }
    .slides{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        animation: slide 3s ease-out infinite;    
    }
    .slide{
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        padding: 100px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
    }
    img{
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-radius: 50%;
        height: 250px;
    }

    h1{
        color: #323232;
        font-size: 32px;
        line-height: 42px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
    }

    h4{
        font-weight: 200;
        line-height: 32px;
        letter-spacing: 0.9px;
        display: flex;
    }

    &:after{
      content: ""; 
      clear: both; 
      display: block; 
    }
```

The closing } were wrong. you can't have a css rule inside another. 
Also the transition timing wasn't doing anything if you are using animation, you can add it to the animation declaration. Transition and animation are two different things. Both have timing function which you can declare on a single line or separately.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I suppose the brackets are ok, I use sass to manage css. Secondly, I knew that solution, but - my mistake - I havent been precise. I want to change those 3 pictures, but on every picture I also want to stop for a few seconds. In that case you wrote, the images floats, and doesnt stop three times.